# Get the container window of a dialog for Hwnd.FromHwnd

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am writing a WPF application using the Calibun Micro framework. It implements an auto-sign off system which will automatically sign a user out of the application after a certain predefined period of inactivity. I check for inactivity using the approach found [here](http://autologoffinwpf.codeplex.com/).

I create dialogs in my application (using windowmanager.showdialog(viewmodel)) which require various user inputs, and I need the auto sign off functionality implemented on those dialogs as well. The issue that I am having is that I cannot seem to get the Hwnd details from a dialog window. I am currently doing the following in my view model:

```
public class BaseViewModel : Screen
{
    public BaseViewModel(User currentUser, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        BaseEventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        CurrentUser = currentUser;

        InitializeTimer();
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        var currentView = GetView();
        if (currentView as Window != null)
        {
            var windowSpecificOsMessageListener = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(currentView as Window).Handle);
        if (windowSpecificOsMessageListener != null)
        {
            windowSpecificOsMessageListener.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(CallBackMethod));
        }

        _autoTimer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = Constants.Seconds * 1000
            };
        _autoTimer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                _autoTimer.Stop();
                _autoTimer.Enabled = false;
                _autoTimer = null;
                BaseEventAggregator.Publish(new SignOutEventMessage());
            };
        _autoTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private IntPtr CallBackMethod(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
    {
        //  Listening OS message to test whether it is a user activity
        if ((msg >= 0x0200 && msg <= 0x020A) || (msg <= 0x0106 && msg >= 0x00A0) || msg == 0x0021)
        {
            ResetAutoTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            // For debugging purpose
            // If this auto logoff does not work for some user activity, you can detect the integer code of that activity  using the following line.
            //Then All you need to do is adding this integer code to the above if condition.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

When the InitializeTimer method executes for a dialog, the result of GetView is null so the auto sign off timer doesn't start and the application doesn't sign off.

Please advise if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have two potential issues:

1. When a viewmodel is instantiated the view isn't attached yet. CMs binding system kicks in and hooks everything up for you, but there are several steps - having everything bound up at constructor time is impossible. Instead override `OnViewAttached` on your VM
2. If you look at the `WindowManager` implementation, you'll see that it actually ensures that the view that it resolves for the VM you are binding is wrapped in a window. This means that `GetView()` actually returns the view for the given VM, which may not necessarily be a window.

Depending on if you are creating `UserControls` or actual `Window` controls the results still might not be correct. I suspect that if you sort issue 1. you will probably run into issue 2.

If so you just need to resolve the `Parent` of the view to get the `Window` that houses it.

Edit: to get the parent of the view you can use the base type `FrameworkElement` which denotes a logical element - it has a `Parent` property which points to the logical parent of the element

You can use something like the following in `OnViewAttached`:

```
override OnViewAttached() 
{
    var view = GetView();

    // Cast the window
    var window = view as Window;

    // If the control wasn't a window
    if(window == null)
    {
        // Cast to FrameworkElement
        var fe = view as FrameworkElement;

        // If it's null throw
        if(fe == null) throw new Exception("View was not present");

        // Otherwise try and cast its parent to a window
        window = fe.Parent as Window;

        // If no window, throw 
        if(window == null) throw new Exception("Window could not be found");     
    }

    // Do stuff
}
```

You could make it an extension method for `IViewAware`

```
public static class IViewAwareExtensions
{
    public static Window TryGetParentWindow(this IViewAware viewAware)
    {
        var view = viewAware.GetView();

        // Cast the window
        var window = view as Window;

        // If the control wasn't a window
        if(window == null)
        {
            // Cast to FrameworkElement
            var fe = view as FrameworkElement;

            // Return null if not found
            if(fe == null) return null;

            // Otherwise try and cast its parent to a window
            window = fe.Parent as Window;

            // If no window, return null
            if(window == null) return null;
        }
    }

    return window;
}
```

Then in `OnViewAttached`:

```
var window = this.TryGetParentWindow();
```

Comment: Additionally, it might be useful to provide this as an external service and inject it into your VM, this way you don't have to write the same code for each view that implements it

Comment: How would I resolve the parent of the view? Could you please give me an example that I could look at?

Comment: Added some code to show how you would check - might be worth making it a utility method or an extension method